# Discord.py Sending attachments for 'say' command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a 'say' command for my bot where it repeats what the user writes in the command message:

```
  @commands.command(name = "say",
                    aliases = ['s'],
                    brief = "Repeats <message>",
                    help = "Repeats <message> passed in after the command."
                    )
  @commands.cooldown(1, cmd_cd, commands.BucketType.user)
  async def say(self, ctx, *, message):
      if ctx.message.attachments:
          await ctx.send(content=message, files=ctx.message.attachments)
      await ctx.send(message)
```

I want it to also include the attachments if the user included any, but i can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting the error:

```
Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: files parameter must be a list of File
```

What am i doing wrong? In the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#:%7E:text=Optional%5Bint%5D-,attachments%C2%B6,-A%20list%20of) it says that the ctx.message.attachments attribute returns a list, so why am I getting this error?
I just want it to send the attachments the exact same way as the user sends it. Is it possible to do this without using embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that it is expecting a `List` of variables of type `File`, but `attachments` retrieves a list of type `attachment`.

If you check the docs for `attachment`, you can see that it can be easily converted to `File` using the method `to_file()`.

So for your function to work you need to pass to `files` a new list containing the Files:

```py
async def say(self, ctx, *, message):
  if ctx.message.attachments:
     new_list = list(map(lambda x:x.to_file(), ctx.message.attachments))
     await ctx.send(content=message, files=new_list)
  await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! While trying your method, it actually gave me [an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69629772/15781748) which is (in my opinion) simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shunya for the help. While trying their method, i found a simpler (in my opinion) way to do it:

```
async def say(self, ctx, *, message):
  if ctx.message.attachments:
     await ctx.send(content=message, files=[await f.to_file() for f in ctx.message.attachments])
  await ctx.send(message)
```